# How set the EventTarget of an Event

Tags: javascript

How to set the [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) of a Event.

```
var myObj = {foo: 'bar'};
var event = new Event('eventName');
event.target = myObj;
```

Will result in the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property target of #<Event> which has only a getter
```

**Edit:**

I want to write something like this, where my class will be the `target`:

```
class MyClass {

  constructor() {
    this.listeners = {};
  }

  addEventListener(type, callback) {
    if (!(type in this.listeners)) {
      this.listeners[type] = [];
    }
    this.listeners[type].push(callback);
  }

  removeEventListener() {
    if (!(type in this.listeners)) {
      return;
    }
    var stack = this.listeners[type];
    for (var i = 0, l = stack.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (stack[i] === callback) {
        stack.splice(i, 1);
        return this.removeEventListener(type, callback);
      }
    }
  }

  dispatchEvent(event) {
    if (!(event.type in this.listeners)) {
      return;
    }
    var stack = this.listeners[event.type];
    event.target = this;
    for (var i = 0, l = stack.length; i < l; i++) {
      stack[i].call(this, event);
    }
  }

}

let myInstance = new MyClass();
let event = new Event('eventName');
myInstance.dispatchEvent();
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but the `EventTarget` is normally automatically set by the browser as the element upon which the event was fired/triggered. What is it that you're trying to do? It *feels*, from the limited information in your question, that you should be using `EventTarget.addEventListener()` but I'm very, very unsure of your intent so far.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Regarding your edit, it ***markedly*** changes the question. The answer now is: Don't use `CustomEvent`, you're trying to use it for something other than its intended purpose. Just use your own object, as you never dispatch the event to a DOM element.

---

It's set automatically when you *dispatch* the event:

```
targetElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

If you want to include custom data other than the element with the event, simply add it as a property:

```
event.data = myObj;
```

Example:

```js
"use strict";
var div = document.getElementById("target");

div.addEventListener(
  "eventName",
  function(e) {
    console.log("e.target:", e.target);
    console.log("e.data:", e.data);
  },
  false
);

var myObj = {foo: "bar"};
var event = new Event("eventName");
event.data = myObj;
div.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: I don't want an DOMElement to be the EventTarget. Instead it should be an Object of my choice.

Comment: @HaNdTriX: Your edit changes the question hugely, almost enough that it should be rolled back. (Fundamentally changing a question after it has answers isn't allowed on SO. I think this *just barely* slips by.) I've edited the answer to address the new question.

Comment: I never mentioned DOM Elements. I tried to reduce my Problem to the essential part.
In Javascript there are many examples where an Event has a target wich is not a DOM Element.
(e.g.: Notification Events) Sorry to be unclear about this.

Comment: @HaNdTriX: You linked to a web-specific interface and used `new Event` in the code. That's quite clearly a question about DOM events. Your updated question is about your own pub/sub system. Anyway, the answer is: Don't use `CustomEvent` (or `Event`).

Comment: Don't 'just add it as a property' — look up the `.detail` field

Comment: Unfortunately `targetElement.dispatchEvent(event);` does not set the target in my event :(

Comment: @Guntram - Well, as you can see it works, so I'd double-check that you're really doing the same thing. If it seems like you are, the questions that you'll probably want to look into are: What's different about your code vs. the working example above? What's `targetElement`? What event constructor are you using? How are you dispatching it? How are you receiving it? How are you determining that `target` isn't set?

Comment: For me, it only worked when working with an element from the DOM: 

`const input = document.getElementById('test-id') as HTMLInputElement;

      input.value = 'TEST';

      const inputEvent = new InputEvent('input', {data: null});

      input.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);`

(but when I create the element via `createElement` it does not attach the target to the event...)

Comment: @Guntram - [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/eqd6fkbw/1/) without being in the DOM. Tested in Chromium-based browsers (Chrome, Edge, Opera, etc.) Firefox, and iOS Safari.

Comment: When I type the stuff from your link directly into the browser it works. When I type it into a test it writes the correct info (with target), but while debugging inside the test, the target is not set after the `dispatchEvent()`-call. Maybe an async/timing problem...

Comment: And thank you for caring so much! :) +1

Answer (score 41):

Okay - I just had a brainwave and so here's another answer for you that's very naughty and *might just work*. (worked for me ;)

Instead of doing `event.target = myObj`, you could try:

```
Object.defineProperty(event, 'target', {writable: false, value: myObj});
```

I may be wrong here, but I think what happens is that the new `target` property hides the original one. It doesn't work the same way as the browser internal event dispatching, and the browser event handling code will almost certainly ignore it, but it might just be enough to fool javascript code that relies on `Event.target`.

Also, be careful to test it in different browsers, as some browsers might define `Event.target` as a non-configurable property.

Comment: This is perfect for unit-testing, thanks for sharing :)

Comment: is it seriously this difficult to do unit-testing of a component in JavaScript in 2023?

Answer (score 0):

It's 1 year, 9 months on from your original question and I want to do exactly this with exactly the same code, from exactly the same place. I know exactly why you want to do this, it's because `EventTarget` isn't a constructable object in all browsers yet. And it would appear that no, there is no real solution to your problem.

In case anybody else has this problem and stumbles across this page, the solution is to not rely on `Event.target`. You can create a custom event and dispatch it like this:

```
var myeventtarget = new MyClass();

var ev = new CustomEvent('myevent', {
    detail: {
        target: myeventtarget
    }});

myeventtarget.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Then, in the event handler, the target can be accessed with:

```
var event_handler = function(ev) {
    var target = ev.detail.target;
    alert(target);
}
```

It's a truly ugly syntax but it looks like the only 'proper' way this can be accomplished right now. Now, if you ignore older browsers, I know that in the newer Firefox and Chrome browsers, you can implement `MyClass` like this:

```
class MyClass extends EventTarget {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}
```

I haven't tested whether the event target is set when dispatched on an object of type `MyClass` given the above definition, but if not, it might be worth suggesting it as a change to the DOM Living Standard since it clearly makes sense. (the spec doesn't currently appear to suggest that it should work)

Lastly, can I caution you against using the javascript `EventTarget` code you are using without checking it works properly first. I found that it breaks when you hand it an `EventListener` object. It also appends a duplicate event if you hand in the same event twice to `addEventListener()`, while the DOM Living Standard clearly states it must not do so. It's fortunately very easy to fix these issues. You need to change `stack[i].call(this, event);` to:

```
if (stack[i].handleEvent) stack[i].handleEvent(event);
        else stack[i].call(this, event);
```

And add the following:

```
var stack = this.listeners[type];
for (var i = 0, l = stack.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (stack[i] === callback){
        return;
    }
}
```

before `this.listeners[type].push(callback);`

Other problems are that `addEventListener()` doesn't simply return if you hand it a null callback (another easy fix), and obviously it doesn't allow options to be handed in to it. (but decide whether you really need this feature)